# Can json files put in webassembly wwwroot folder be changed by a malicious user?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I have a settings.json file with a property relating to my authentication and authorization mechanism in my blazor webassembly project client.

Can a malicious user change its settings? what about put this setting directly in a class service that needs it?

Comment: Well, anything can be changed by a malicious user.

Comment: if it is actually stored in wwwroot, a user is able to read the file. He is also able to change the file *in his browser*. Unless you majorly f****d up, he is not able to change it for other users / change it on the server.